# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java

estoy tratando de conectar Mysql con Netbeans, y quiero modificar la base de datos a partir de un menu sencillo creado con java desde Netbeans, pero al momento de ejecutar obtengo este error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No soportado
at conexion.Conexion.conexion(Conexion.java:22)
at conexion.evento.main(evento.java:17)
C:\Users\ale\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

Tengo dos clases creadas. En una donde establezco la conexion con Mysql y la otra donde creo el menu que me ayudara a modificar la base de datos. No estoy segura de que se me esta pasando.
En la primera clase coloco el menu que es:

```
 evento.java



    Conexion cn=new Conexion();
    Connection con= cn.conexion(); //Esta es la linea 17 donde señala el error

    //Creación del menu
```

Y LA segunda CLASE es donde establezco la conexion con Mysql:Conexion.java

```
package conexion;
```

````
        import java.sql.DriverManager;
        import java.sql.SQLException;

        public class Conexion {
           //Para la conexión
         Connection con;
        public Conexion(){
           try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/evento","root","");
               System.out.println("Conexión exitosa");
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }        
          }

          Connection conexion() {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No soportado"); //esta es la linea 22
            }
         }```

En neatbens no me marca error, solo al momento de correr es cuando ya nada funciona. Me manda directo al error.
````

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque el código lanza un error explícitamente, por eso da error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `conexion()` lanza una excepción, no hace nada más. Si el propósito de ese método es devolver la conexión el código debería ser así:

```
Connection conexion() {
       return con;
 }
```